# Prove convergence of a series

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $$M=\{2^k*3^l|k,l \in \mathbb{N}\}$$ and $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ a sequence which takes the numbers from M and sorts them ascending i.e :$$1,2,3,4,6,8,9,12,16...$$

Let $$b_n=\frac{1}{a_n}$$

Prove that the series: $$s_n=\sum_{k=0}^n bk $$ converges and determine the limit: $$ s=\sum_{k=0}^\infty bk $$

My idea here was to rewrite the $\sum_{k=0}^n bk$ as a product of two geometric series. So I wrote down $s_n=\sum_{k=0}^n bk$ as $\sum_{\substack{k=0\\j=0}}^n \frac{1}{2^k*3^l}$ (not sure if I'm actually allowed to do it like this...) and tried to split them somehow to the form of $s_n=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{2^k} * \sum_{j=0}^n \frac{1}{3^j}$ 
But it clearly doesn't work like this. Maybe there is an another way to prove it with the comparison theorem I thought, but I'm totally new to this, and still need some hints to tackle this.

Comment: As an aside, these are called [smooth numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number). See [OEIS A$003586$](http://oeis.org/A003586).

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$s = \sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k
= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k3^j}
= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \bigg( \frac{1}{2^k} \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{1}{3^j} \bigg)
= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k}\times\frac{3}{2}
= 3.$$
As the sum is finite, all steps are valid.

Comment: Is this also a proof that this series converges?

Comment: Yes. Read the equation from the right to the left. All equalities are valid, so the sum must converge.